# Vee-validate seems to validate a XSS threat email address - is extra sanitation required?

Tags: xss, email-validation, vee-validate

i'm using vee-validate in a vue app to validate an email address input which works fine except that i notice that it validates this address:

[image]

as true.

i'm trying to protect my site from XSS attack and came across an article mentioning the possibility of of an attacker using the email input to attack the site. apparantly if the email input accepts the above email address then the site is vulnerable to attack.

i tested some email validators on fiddle and they all seem to invalidate the above email address. unfortunately, vee-validate validates the address. (i'm using the required|email rules).

is this an error on the part of vee-validate or am i implementing it incorrectly? it would be nice if vee-validate prevented XSS via the email validation rule.

how to prevent XSS via email input, should i sanitize the email input after vee-validation?

Answer (score 1):

Vee-validate uses another library to handle validation of email addresses ([validator.js](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js)).  [That validator](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/blob/master/src/lib/isEmail.js) mostly follows the RFC2822 spec for email addresses... And strings in quotes is almost all allowed by that.

It seems to me that vee-validate is doing the right thing here.

Generally, you will want to defend against XSS attacks in your backend.  Any real hacker will not be using your website to generate attacks on the server.  They will use their own tools to inject whatever data they want and have your page upload it to the server.

A good rule of thumb on the server-side is to strip anything that looks like an HTML tag from all user input.  You will find libraries in every server to handle this.  For instance, I use perl and run all user input through the [HTML::Restrict](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Restrict) library.

Comment: thanks for your valued response. however i am still a bit confused as to how to clean up email addresses, like the one in my question, server side. i use AWS cognito, so the email address goes straight to cognito so i can't touch it. they send confirmation email to client so if its not a valid email, no problem (i think). however, if i were to clean the email before submitting to cognito, then surely the email address (if it was a valid address) will no longer be valid if i have remove characters from it?

Comment: AWS Cognito will not accept that email address I bet, so just make sure you check for errors coming back from the service and display them appropriately.

Comment: hi, thanks for the follow up. i checked in the cognito dashboard and the email address has been accepted both for 1) if i change the email address for a user and 2) if i sign up a new user. in both cases, the email address is marked as un-verified as it awaits a confirmation code to be returned by the user, unfortunately the email containing the code has been sent to the un-verified address. no problem if its a new sign-up because i won't access that email address but for the change of address, i would access it.